# How can I implement CSS into React native

Tags: react-native

I am either overthinking this or missing the core concepts of how CSS and html work within React Native.

I have this CSS code that I provided below that creates an inverted border radius tab like the tabs on google chrome.

I understand that you can use stylesheets in react native to implement CSS but I know these are formatted differently.

**How can I implement this CSS code in a react native app?** [Snack io](https://snack.expo.dev/) is a great tool to be able to quickly implement this if you would like to link your demo to me.

CSS

```
body {
        background: #1c1c1c;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .tab {
        float: left;

        width: 90px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        height: 30px;

        position: relative;

        background: #fff;

        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }

    .tab:before,
    .tab:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;

        height: 10px;
        width: 20px;

        bottom: 0;
    }

    .tab:after {
        right: -20px;

        border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;

        -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #fff;
        box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #fff;
    }

    .tab:before {
        left: -20px;

        border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #fff;
        box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #fff;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a file with js extension, example styles.js and then import the file with `import MyStyles from 'YOUR_RUTE_FILE'`

The other way is in the same file

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native
```

And write your styles

```
const stylesRNP = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
//Styles...
}
});
```